# LTC3780 Test load for adjusting current limit

Tags: power-supply, resistors

I use the LTC3780 for my variable power supply, it can handle 1-30VDC and 7A output.

In order to be able to view my current limit adjustments, i thought to create a momentary test load by using a 4.7 Ohm 50W resistor.

Do you think this is safe?
If not what other options do i have?

Thanks

Comment: Schematic? What did you program the current limit to?

Comment: I use the WD2002SJ module, datasheet: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Marzogh/Benchtop-Powersupply/master/Datasheets/WD2002SJ%20-%20LTC3780%20buck%20boost%20converter.pdf

Comment: 7Amp into 4.7 ohms is ~>200Watt... how about four 50 W resistors?  (I've abused power resistors one or two times, but eventually they fail.)

Comment: Wouldn't a 1 ohm 50W resistor do the job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the current. The maximum current thru the resistor is (30 V)/(4.7 Ω) = 6.4 A.  Since your supply can source 7 A, there should be no problem here.

Check the power.  The dissipation is (30 V)<sup>2</sup>/(4.7 Ω) = 191 W.  Oops, that's too much for a 50 W resistor.

So no, this is not "safe", if you mean safe is sticking to all the worst case limits.

Comment: Thanks, if i'm correct then i would go for a 10 Ohm 100W resistor.  Max current would be 3A, which is still way more than what i would usually need. In most cases i'd adjust from 0.01 to 1A.

Comment: @Deck: A 10 Ohm resistor would draw 3 A and dissipate 90 W.  The 3 A is within the limits for this supply.  You'd have to make sure that this 10 Ohm resistor can safely dissipate 90 W.